# increase number of white spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex, whitespace

I have a problem in c# about increasing white space number in my string. For example, i have a string like this : "I   have a  problem". I want to increase the number of white spaces by one. So if i have between the word "I" and "have" 3 white spaces, between "have" and "a" 1 white space etc. , i would like to increment all white spaces by 1, so that the 3 becomes 4 and 1 becomes 2...

Is it possible using regex or not? I've searched about this problem and always got how to replace multiple white spaces with one, but not increasing them.

I hope someone can help me.

Best regards, Stefan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search by this:

```
"( +)"
```

and replace by this:

```
"$1 "
```

UPDATE: decrease by one:

```
"( *) "
```

and replace by:

```
"$1"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1gYgFh/17)

C# code Sample [Run it here](http://ideone.com/2B065x)

```
    String pattern = "( +)";
    String substitution = "$1 ";
    String input = "a b  c   d    e";
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
    string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

Comment: That was fast!. Thank you a lot!

Comment: And now  the question, how can i decrease it by one?